# How to use sympy to locally switch to use of "set of equations" from standard sequence of lines of assignments?

Tags: python, sympy

The following Python function has a flaw in the sequence of steps of calculating f(x).

```
def f(x):
   f = np.zeros((3))
   f[0] = x[0]
   f[1] = f[2] + x[1]
   f[2] = x[2]
   return f
```

The input x= [1,1,1] gives [1,1,1] but should give [1,2,1] provided we interpret the code mathematically as a system of equations. How can I use sympy to sort out the evaluation order and get the "right" answer?

Note, I am not at all looking for solving the equations system symbolically, but just want the evaluation order correct and avoid work with mapping out that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sympy, you could write the function as:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
    f = symbols('f0:3')
    sol = solve([Eq(f[0], x[0]), Eq(f[1], f[2] + x[1]), Eq(f[2], x[2])], f)
    return np.array([sol[fi].evalf() for fi in f], dtype=float)

f(np.array([1, 1, 1]))
```

This supposes that you are only using a simple example, and that in reality the equations are much more complicated.  Note that the approach can get more involved if your equations have more than one valid solution.

`lambdify()` can convert an expression to numpy format. For this to work here, the function `f` should get some symbolic input parameters and convert them to output expressions.

Here is how it could look like.

```py
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, lambdify

def f(x):
    y = symbols('y0:3')
    sol = solve([Eq(y[0], x[0]), Eq(y[1], y[2] + x[1]), Eq(y[2], x[2])], y)
    return [sol[yi].simplify() for yi in y]

x0, x1, x2 = symbols('x0:3')
f_np = lambdify((x0, x1, x2), f((x0, x1, x2)))

# calling the function on a 1D numpy array
f_np(*np.array([1, 1, 1]))

# calling the function on a 2D numpy array and convert the result back to a numpy array
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
np.array(f_np(a[:, 0], a[:, 1], a[:, 2])).T  # array([[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 2]])
```

Here, `f_np` is a numpy function that gets three inputs (the `*` [unpacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call) the array) and has a list of 3 as output. Directly working with arrays as input and output doesn't seem possible at the moment.

In an interactive environment, you can enter [`f_np?`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#accessing-help) (or `f_np??`) to see that functions source:

```py
>> f_np?
Signature: f_np(x0, x1, x2)
Docstring:
Created with lambdify. Signature:
func(x0, x1, x2)
Expression:
(x0, x1 + x2, x2)
Source code:
def _lambdifygenerated(x0, x1, x2):
    return ((x0, x1 + x2, x2))
```

`f_np` can then be used in scipy optimizers and even be compiled (Cython or numba). This approach assumes the equations stay the same.

Comment: Yes! With a small change in the second equation that should be f[2]+ x[1].

Comment: Follow-up question: does simpler symbolhandling like this slow down execution, or make it perhaps quicker compared to just write up imperative code? I plan to involve this kind of function in scipy optimisation using minimise and it will be excused many times.

Comment: It would be much slower using sympy.

Comment: Is here a way to "compile" this function using Cython somehow? After all, once the function has been used once and sympy done the job to get the right sequence of calculations the same should be re-used again and again, possibly with different parameters updated in the function during optimisation? It is ok also with guiding yes/no answer here. Just heard about Cython.

Comment: Cython won't be of help when `sympy.solve` is part of the function. Sympy's `lambdify` (converting a sympy expression to numpy) would be of help if `solve` is used to create such an expression.

Comment: I just added an example to convert the function to numpy via lambdify

Comment: You say in the last added example that "this approach assumes the equations stay the same". Does this mean that you cannot change a parameter in the function f_np - central for the way I think of use together with minimise().

Comment: You can change the 3 input parameters freely. But you  can't easily use a different relationship between the input and output.  Maybe you can create a new question with an example a bit closer to how you want to use minimizing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can let sympy calculate the formulas for f0, f1 and f2:

```
import sympy as sym
f0, f1, f2 = sym.symbols('f0,f1,f2')
x0, x1, x2 = sym.symbols('x0,x1,x2')

eq1 = sym.Eq(f0, x0)
eq2 = sym.Eq(f1, f2 + x1)
eq3 = sym.Eq(f2, x2)

result = sym.solve([eq1,eq2, eq3],(f0, f1, f2))
print(result)
>>> {f0: x0, f1: x1 + x2, f2: x2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You fundamentally misunderstand what `=` does in Python. It's not mathematical equality (which works both ways), it's *assignment*. When you say `a = b` you say "forget whatever `a` was, it's `b` from now on".

So going step-by-step we get:

```
   f[0] = x[0]         # f[0] becomes x[0] = 1
   f[1] = f[2] + x[1]  # f[1] becomes f[2] + x[1] = 0 + 1 = 1
   f[2] = x[2]         # f[2] becomes x[2] = 1
```

---

> Note, I am not at all looking for solving the equations system symbolically, but just want the evaluation order correct and avoid work with mapping out that myself.

You're either going to need to solve the equations symbolically yourself, or do it with a computer algebra system. Regular Python code is imperative and does neither of these things (out of the box).

See e.g. kabooya's answer for setting up such a system of equations using Sympy.

Comment: The purpose for me is to in the function switch from imperative to declarative code to improve readability and also simplify. What I am looking for is more what JohanC provide below.